# How to make an interactive simple watch in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a bit confused with how to create a watch in python
I wrote the follow code:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

tt='vv'

def time(tt):
    from time import strftime
    tt=strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    return tt

Label= Label(root,bd=11,text=time(tt))
Label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

How may I make it interactive? now it just shows the time which was at the moment of running program

Comment: so by "interactive" you don't mean you want the user to interact with it, but you want to update the clock about once a second, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `after` function to schedule a method call.

Here's a little example. Note that I am using a [`StringVar`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) to easily set the text of the `Label`.

```
from Tkinter import *
from time import strftime

root = Tk()

time_var = StringVar()

def set_time():
    time_var.set(strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    root.after(1000, set_time)

Label(root, bd=11, textvariable=time_var).pack()
set_time()
root.mainloop()
```

I call `set_time` once, and then `set_time` schedules itself to be called every 1000 ms.

Comment: where did you find the after function?) I coudn't find it in the documentation(

Comment: after(delay_ms, callback=None, *args) [#]
Registers an alarm callback that is called after a given time.
oh, I've found)
This method registers a callback function that will be called after a given number of milliseconds. Tkinter only guarantees that the callback will not be called earlier than that; if the system is busy, the actual delay may be much longer.

Comment: You can stop an indiviuell call to `after` by calling `after_cancel`. `after` returns an ID which you can then pass to `after_cancel`. To stop the updating altogether, just stop calling `root.after(...)` in `set_time` (just add some condition like a flag or something).

Comment: yes, I did read about that but it's a wall :) I put my affect below)

Comment: Your method `recc` creates a new local variable `akt_var` and hides the *global* variable `akt_var`. You can fix this by putting `global akt_var` as first line in your `recc` function to tell python that you want to use the global `akt_var` instead of creating a new, local one. Put please in future ask a new question instead of posting follow-up questions as comments or as answers.

Comment: I wonder why you find *easier* to use an additional `StringVar` instead than `label["text"] = ...`